# Get dynamic data in radio button values and update MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a dashboard and I have one page and I have set three navigation tabs in one page with on click events where I can navigate through tab links in one page.

In Navigation tab I have users tab where I can access all users data. In user area I have change role button when I click on button the popup will appear and have radio buttons with two buttons (YES or NO).
The only thing I want to achieve is to pass an user id to popup box, get dynamic values into radio button from database in popup box('already implement but it doesn't show values it shows only radio buttons') and change user roles without page refresh and stay on current tab.

Here is my code:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_users, tbl_user_roles WHERE tbl_users.user_role_id = tbl_user_roles.user_role_id");
        $i = 1;
        while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i++?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fetch['Username']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fetch['email']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fetch['role']?></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="show_dialog()" id="btn-show-dialog">Change Role</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

popup box

```
<div class="overlay-roles" id="dialog-container">
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="popup-roles">
        <?php 
            $roles_query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_user_roles");
            while ($roles = mysqli_fetch_array($roles_query)){
                $user_role = $roles['user_role'];
                echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='radio' value='<?php echo $user_role>'  /></td></tr>";
            }
        ?>
            <div class="text-right">
                <button  class="conf-dialog-btn-no" id="ignore">Cancel</button>
                <button name="delete-user" class="conf-dialog-btn-yes" id="confirm">Apply</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

javascript to hande popup show/hide

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("btn-show-dialog").onclick = function(){show_dialog()};
    
    var overlayme = document.getElementById("dialog-container");
    function show_dialog() {
        overlayme.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    document.getElementById("confirm").onclick = function(){confirm()};
    function confirm() {/   
        overlayme.style.display = "none";
    }
    
    document.getElementById("cancel").onclick = function(){cancel()};
    function cancel() {
        overlayme.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In the javascript you assign various functions as `event handlers` before the functions are defined. In one of these functions ( `confirm()` ) you have an erronous leading slash `/` and `confirm` is a standard js function

Comment: If you need to get the `user id` and pass that to PHP for further processing why have you not used the user id anywhere in the HTML output? You could easily assign it as a parameter to `show_dialog` or access it from within the same row ( if it were there somehow ) using sibling selectors

Comment: i replace $i auto increment with $fetch User_id what to do now???